# calling a function in javascript after a period of time has passed

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

I'm trying to write a function that will auto suggest what the user means when they type into an input field. Right now I have all of the auto suggest code complete but in my javascript I can't get to the first if in toggleGenusInput no matter what I do (this first if queries the database through php and gets the suggestions).

Does anyone know how I could modify my code so that if something is typed in the input field and is not changed after 2 seconds it will enter that first if? Thanks.

Here are my script globals:

```
var time = new Date();
var timeout = 2000; //query db every 2 seconds of not typing anything
var autoSuggest = true;
var lastQueryTyped = "";
var queryTypedAt = time.getTime(); //what time the last new text was entered
```

Here's the function that's connected to an input node's onfocus method:

```
function toggleGenusInput(inputNode) {
    if(autoSuggest) {
        if((time.getTime() - queryTypedAt) >= timeout && inputNode.value == lastQueryTyped) {
            //the input has not changed and it's reached the timeout time, requery the db

            responseDoc = getXMLFrom("getsimilaritems.php?query=" + inputNode.value);

            if(queryFindsSuggestions(responseDoc)) {
                cleanUpSuggestions();
                appendSuggestions(inputNode, responseDoc);
            }
        }
        else if(inputNode.value != lastQueryTyped) {
            //something new was entered so update the time and what was put in

            lastQueryTyped = inputNode.value;
            queryTypedAt = time.getTime();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the html object that function is attached to:

```
<input type="text" name="autoSuggestInput" onfocus="toggleGenusInput(document.myForm.autoSuggestInput)" />
```

Comment: [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: @sje397, thanks for showing me that. However, in this program I need that timeout function to be continuously called (so whatever function it's given needs to be called once every 2 seconds). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: setInterval is almost the same, but will call your specified code repeatedly until you issue 'clearInterval'.

Comment: Have you looked at the oogles of autosuggest scripts on the web? Most good ones already do everything you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) and bind the handler to the `keyup` event instead:

```
function toggleGenusInput(inputNode) {
    if(autoSuggest) {
        if(_timeout) {
           clearTimeout(_timeout);
        }
        _timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            //the input has not changed and it's reached the timeout time, requery the db 
            responseDoc = getXMLFrom("getsimilaritems.php?query=" + inputNode.value);

            if(queryFindsSuggestions(responseDoc)) {
                cleanUpSuggestions();
                appendSuggestions(inputNode, responseDoc);
            }

        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

and

```
<input type="text" name="autoSuggestInput" onkeyup="toggleGenusInput(document.myForm.autoSuggestInput)" />
```

Now whenever a key is pressed (not on focus), your function will be called and wait a certain time to execute the functionality. If another timeout is running, it will be canceled first (otherwise you would keep creating timeouts over and over again while the user inserts text which would lead to strange results).